# Not a valid BCrypt hash. error is occuring

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a problem in comparing method of bcrypt. This mthod is not able to compare password properly. Please sort out me from this problem.There is problem with comparing method its not working.I have a problem in comparing method of bcrypt. This mthod is not able to compare password properly. Please sort out me from this problem.There is problem with comparing method its not working.

```
  app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {

                // hash and save a password
              const pass = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password);
              const username = req.body.username;
              console.log(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, pass));
              const sql = "INSERT INTO data ( password, username ) values (?,?)";
              db.query(sql, [pass, username], (err, rows, fields) =>  {
                                       if(!err){
                                                 res.send({
                                                   key: rows
                                                 });
                                               }
                                                 else {
                                                   console.log(err);
                                                 }
                                     });
        })

        app.post('/show', (req, res) => {

          const username = req.body.username;
          const password = req.body.password;

          db.query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username = ?",[username], function(err, results){
            if (err) {
                    // console.log("error ocurred",error);
                    res.send({
                    "code":400,
                    "failed":"err ocurred"
                    })
                  }else{
                    if(results.length >0){

                    // console.log(bcrypt.compareSync(password, results[0].password));

                      if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, results[0].password)){
                                res.send({
                                "code":200,
                                "success":"login sucessfull"
                                });
                            }
                            else{
                                res.send({
                                "code":204,
                                "success":"Email and password does not match"
                                });
                            }

                    }else{
                          res.send({
                          "code":204,
                          "success":"Email does not exits"
                          });
                          console.log(results.length);
                          }
                  }

          })

        })
```

Comment: The indentation here is really irregular and it's making this code hard to folllow.

Comment: If you're using something like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) you can use `async`/`await` to really simplify this code. Callbacks can be a lot of hassle to work with.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the saved password field is for the password `test`?